# Fourier transformation of $\log(p^2-i0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, contour-integration, distribution-theory, quantum-field-theory

In "Renormalized Quantum Yang-Mills Theory on curved spacetime" it is stated on page 59 that the Fourier transformation of $\log(p^2-i0)$ is given by
$-\frac{1}{2} \partial^2\left( \frac{\log(\xi^2+i0)}{\xi^2+i0}\right)$ (see (227))

I have tried several methods but I am not able to show this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $i0$? Maybe you meant $i_0$.

Comment: $+i0$ is the epsilon description for distributions similiar to the one in the feynman propagator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Position_space

Comment: It just means taking the limit in the sense of distributions when $\varepsilon\to 0$

Comment: I am really stuck on this so even a hint might suffice for me to give it another try.